# Run a command from a module based on the user's choice

Tags: python, function, variables, input, module

So i have the current code:

```py
module = input('What module?: ')
print(module.run())
```

& the goal is that it'll do the run() function of a pre-made module, which module in question is being chosen by the user.

Comment: should using les exception try and except

Comment: `importlib.import_module` may help.

Comment: how can i use `importlib.import_module` here? it does seem like the solution but i dont know how to use it lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
def module1():
    return "module 1 called"
def module2():
    return "module 2 called"

module = input("What module?: ")
function_call = module + "()"

print(eval(function_call))
```

The eval function is used to call a function from a string.
Because i added "()" the input just needs to be "module1" or "module2" it is according to the name of the function minus the "()"

hope this helps :)